# Flutter - Provider is taking too long to change boolean variable

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, state-management

I am creating an app where i am using `NotificationListener<UserScrollNotification>` to change the boolean value on the basis of scroll direction... but when i scroll page for very first time all the content gets disappear for 2-3 seconds...I am using Provider.... Please help me...

Here i am trying to change boolean variable

```
NotificationListener<UserScrollNotification>(
                               onNotification: (notification) {
                              final ScrollDirection direction =
                                  notification.direction;

                              if (direction == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
                                value.changeVisiblity(true);
                              } else if (direction ==
                                  ScrollDirection.forward) {
                                value.changeVisiblity(false);
                              }

                              return false;
                            },
```

here is my provider class where boolean is defined

```
bool isVisible = false;
  changeVisiblity(bool value) {
    isVisible = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

here is short video

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zglPBhtaII54lXhu6RRThkMV8xtqYTK-/view)

Comment: And wrap the widget you want to change according to the scroll state with a ValueListenableBuilder, connect the notifier you created to the listenable parameter and that's it.

Comment: Can you please explain it little more? I'm still stuck :(

Comment: I added an example as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  SampleWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final ValueNotifier<bool> isVisibility = ValueNotifier(false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: isVisibility,
                builder: (BuildContext context, bool value, Widget? child) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      const Spacer(),
                      Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                          child: AnimatedCrossFade(
                            firstChild: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    value == false ? const Icon(Icons.food_bank_rounded) : const SizedBox(),
                                    const Text("Food"),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    value == false ? const Icon(Icons.people) : const SizedBox(),
                                    const Text("Fashion"),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    value == false ? const Icon(Icons.face) : const SizedBox(),
                                    const Text("Beauty"),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            secondChild: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: const [
                                Text("Food"),
                                Text("Fashion"),
                                Text("Beauty"),
                              ],
                            ),
                            crossFadeState: value == false ? CrossFadeState.showFirst : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                          )),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 7,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index == 0) {
                    return VisibilityDetector(
                      onVisibilityChanged: (info) {
                        if (info.visibleFraction < 1) {
                          isVisibility.value = true;
                        } else {
                          isVisibility.value = false;
                        }
                      },
                      key: ValueKey(index),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text("$index"),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text("$index"),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i am getting exact same error with this method too

Comment: i think the problem is with notificationListener... is there any other way to detect scroll except NotificationListener

Comment: one more thing, i only get this situation on a very first time when app starts...

Comment: is there any way to see my logs which can show me why everything gets disapper for some seconds... right now i am getting no logs during this process

Comment: I created a new example for you

Comment: It works like this, when you wrap the first item of the list with VisibilityDetector and the first item comes out of the visible part, it changes in the menu buttons.
hope it helps

Comment: can you please see my code over TeamViewer?

Comment: I noticed new thing that this error happens when i am using Notification  Listener inside future builder

Comment: if i use it without Future builder then it works fine

Comment: I prefer google meets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248733/discussion-between-usman-hafeez-and-rasityilmaz).

Comment: I lost your github link, can you please share that again? please

Comment: Please check chat